# Azure Application Insights capturing HTTP dependencies ONLY on local machine

Tags: azure-application-insights

When I debug my .net 4.6.2 application, the application insights panel work perfectly shows every HTTP dependencies. But when I deploy my code to dev/uat/homol/stg I'm not getting those dependencies... It's important to notice that SQL dependencies are being logged as expected, like other items such as requests and metrics... There are no clear error, warnings or other signals.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you please share your code and configuration file?

Comment: Please share the code where you have configured ApplicationInsighst and Configuration file.